# camera's near field update

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there any way to change camera's near and far parameters without re-creation of camera

Because camera stops showing objects when I try to change them

in some cases, it just shows black screen (even there is skybox)

Before: [image]

After near parameter change:
[image]

All the button does:

```
function changeNear() {
  camera.near = 0;
  console.log(camera.near)
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/random-jordan/pen/gOeYjpa?editors=1111

Comment: The .near value has to be greater than 0, as outlined in the docs: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=perspe#api/en/cameras/PerspectiveCamera.near

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to recreate the camera.

You are not seeing the objects because `near: 10` is too far away so the objects don't get rendered.

Try setting near to 0.1 by default and setting it to 2.5 in `changeNear()`. You will see that `near` gets changed just enough so that the objects get cut a bit.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot
I guess i was setting camera.near = 0 so it produces black screen